# How can i prevent textView in constraint view from going of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a textview in constraint layout that keeps its constraints in an emulator. but when i run the app on a physical phone, the textview goes of the screen

here is the complete xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageDeal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDeal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageDeal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/Text_Margin_Standard"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_price"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Textview with id **tvprice** is what goes of screen when run from physical device

Comment: Try to remove "app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"" from tvprice

Answer (score 0):

Change the width to `0dp`, this would set it to `match_constraint`in editor which means TextView will respect its constraints when setting its width.

Setting width to `wrap_content` will let the TextView change its width based on content regardless of layout width.

```
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: @rkay you also need to set its right/end constraint

Comment: `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  android:layout_width="0dp"` aligns it to the left. i need the text view to the right

Comment: @rkay can you show a screenshot from design editor in Android Studio?

Comment: @rkay from the looks of it, the constraints are not properly set, are you nesting anything by any chance?

Comment: Am not nesting anything

Comment: @rkay did you try *removing* gravity?

Comment: @rkay Also, there might be a problem with layout Editor, run the code on device, it should work fine

Comment: The code works fine on emulator but does not work fine on physical device. And about the gravity , yeah i tried removing it but had the same problem

Comment: Did you try it on device *after* setting width to 0dp and setting constraint?

Comment: yes i tried it on the device after setting width to 0dp

Comment: You have two declarations for `app` it might be causing issue:
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` remove it and seeif it works

Answer (score 0):

Replace the TextView with this one

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="end" />
```

Comment: sorry android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: This aligns textView to the left but  i need the text view to the right

Comment: use this in you textView xml  android:gravity="end"

Comment: Using gravity makes the text go off screen

Comment: can you provide complete xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **relative layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:tint="@color/text_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleRow"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:text="name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArrow"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:text="subtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitleRow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArrow"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:tint="@color/text_black"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have tried relative layout too, works on emulator but does not work on device unless i hard code the position, which will get messed up with a device with a different screen size